# Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk-usage

When I sum up the sizes of my files, I get one figure. If I run `du`, I get another figure. If I run `du` on all the files on my partition, it doesn't match what `df` claims is used. Why are there so many different figures for the total size of my files? Can't computers add?

Speaking of adding: when I add the “Used” and “Available” columns of `df`, I don't get the total figure. And that total figure is smaller than the size of my partition. And if I add up my partition sizes I don't get my disk size! What gives?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Adding up numbers is easy. The problem is, there are many different numbers to add.

### How much disk space does a file use?

The basic idea is that a file containing *n* bytes uses *n* bytes of disk space, plus a bit for some control information: the file's metadata (permissions, timestamps, etc.), and a bit of overhead for the information that the system needs to find where the file is stored. However there are many complications.

#### Microscopic complications

Think of each file as a series of books in a library. Smaller files make up just one volume, but larger files consist of many volumes, like an encyclopedia. In order to be able to locate the files, there is a card catalog which references every volume. Each volume has a bit of overhead due to the covers. If a file is very small, this overhead is relatively large. Also the card catalog itself takes up some room.

Going a bit more technical, in a typical simple filesystem, the space is divided in **blocks**. A typical block size is 4KiB. Each file takes up an integer number of blocks. Unless the file size is a multiple of the block size, the last block is only partially used. So a 1-byte file and a 4096-byte file both take up 1 block, whereas a 4097-byte file takes up two blocks. You can observe this with `ls` or `du`: if your filesystem has a 4KiB block size, then `ls -s` and `du` will report 4KiB for a 1-byte file.

If a file is large, then additional blocks are needed just to store the list of blocks that make up the file (these are **[indirect blocks](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2008/12/24/understanding-indirect-blocks-in-unix-file-systems/)**; more sophisticated filesystems may optimize this in the form of **[extents](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/12/20/digital-forensics-understanding-ext4-part-1-extents)**). Those don't show in the file size as reported by `ls -l` or GNU `du --apparent-size`. `du` and `ls -s`, which report disk usage as opposed to size, does account for them.

Some filesystems try to reuse the free space left in the last block to [pack several file tails in the same block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation). Some filesystems (such as [ext4 since Linux 3.8](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.8#head-372b38979138cf2006bd0114ae97f889f67ef46a) use 0 blocks for tiny files (just a few bytes) that entirely fit in the inode.

#### Macroscopic complications

Generally, as seen above, the total size reported by `du` is the sum of the sizes of the blocks or extents used by the file.

The size reported by `du` may be smaller if the file is compressed. Unix systems traditionally support a crude form of compression: if a file block contains only null bytes, then instead of storing a block of zeroes, the filesystem can omit that block altogether. A file with omitted blocks like this is called a **[sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)**. Sparse files are not automatically created when a file contains a large series of null bytes, the application must arrange for the file to become sparse.

Some filesystems such as [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression) and [zfs](https://blogs.oracle.com/observatory/entry/zfs_compression_a_win_win) support general-purpose **compression**.

#### Advanced complications

Two major features of very modern filesystems such as zfs and btrfs make the relationship between file size and disk usage significantly more distant: snapshots and deduplication.

**[Snapshots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_(computer_storage))** are a frozen state of the filesystem at a certain date. Filesystems that support this feature can contain multiple snapshots taken at different dates. These snapshots take room, of course. At one extreme, if you delete all the files from the active version of the filesystem, the filesystem won't become empty if there are snapshots remaining.

Any file or block that hasn't changed since a snapshot, or between two snapshots was taken exists identically in the snapshot and in the active version or other snapshot. This is implemented via [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). In some edge cases, it's possible that deleting a file on a full filesystem will fail due to insufficient available space — because removing that file would require making a copy of a block in the directory, and there's no more room for even that one block.

**[Deduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication)** is a storage optimization technique that consists of avoiding storing identical blocks. With typical data, looking for duplicates isn't always worth the effort. Both [zfs](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/zfs_dedup) and [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication) support deduplication as an optional feature.

### Why is the total from `du` different from the sum of the file sizes?

As we've seen above, the size reported by `du` for each file is normally is the sum of the sizes of the blocks or extents used by the file. Note that by default, `ls -l` lists sizes in bytes, but `du` lists sizes in KiB, or in 512-byte units (sectors) on some more traditional systems (`du -k` forces the use of kilobytes). Most modern unices support `ls -lh` and `du -h` to use “human-readable” numbers using K, M, G, etc. suffices (for KiB, MiB, GiB) as appropriate.

When you run `du` on a directory, it sums up the disk usage of all the files in the directory tree, **including the directories** themselves. A directory contains data (the names of the files, and a pointer to where the file's metadata is), so it needs a bit of storage space. A small directory will take up one block, a larger directory will require more blocks. The amount of storage used by a directory sometimes depends not only on the files it contains but also the order in which they were inserted and in which some files are removed (with some filesystems, this can leave holes — a compromise between disk space and performance), but the difference will be tiny (an extra block here and there). When you run `ls -ld /some/directory`, the directory's size is listed. (Note that the “total NNN” line at the top of the output from `ls -l` is an unrelated number, it's the sum of the sizes in blocks of the listed items, expressed in KiB or sectors.)

Keep in mind that `du` includes **[dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments)** which `ls` doesn't show unless you use the `-A` or `-a` option.

Sometimes `du` reports less than the expected sum. This happens if there are **[hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)** inside the directory tree: `du` counts each file only once. Use `du -l` switch to count files *N* times if they have *N* hard links.

On some file systems like `ZFS` on Linux, `du` does not report the full disk space occupied by extended attributes of a file.

Beware that if there are mount points under a directory, `du` will count all the files on these mount points as well, unless given the `-x` option. So if for instance you want the total size of the files in your root filesystem, run `du -x /`, not `du /`.

[If a filesystem is mounted to a non-empty directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41336/where-do-the-files-go-if-you-mount-a-drive-to-a-folder-that-already-contains-fil), the files in that directory are hidden by the mounted filesystem. They still occupy their space, but `du` won't find them.

#### Deleted files

When a file is **deleted**, this only removes the directory entry, not necessarily the file itself. Two conditions are necessary in order to actually delete a file and thus reclaim its disk space:

- The file's link count must drop to 0: if a file has multiple hard links, removing one doesn't affect the others.
- As long as the file is open by some process, the data remains. Only when all processes have closed the file is the file deleted. The output [`fuser -m`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)) or [`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) on a mount point includes the processes that have a file open on that filesystem, even if the file is deleted.
- even if no process has the deleted file open, the file's space may not be reclaimed if that file is the backend of a `loop` device. `losetup -a` (as `root`) can tell you which `loop` devices are currently set up and on what file. The loop device must be destroyed (with `losetup -d`) before the disk space can be reclaimed.

If you delete a file in some file managers or GUI environments, it may be put into a trash area where it can be undeleted. As long as the file can be undeleted, its space is still consumed.

### What are these numbers from `df` exactly?

A typical filesystem contains:

- Blocks containing file (including directories) data and some metadata (including indirect blocks, and extended attributes on some filesystems).
- Free blocks.
- Blocks that are reserved to the root user.
- superblocks and other control information.
- [Inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)
- A [journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system)

Only the first kind is reported by `du`. When it comes to `df`, what goes into the “used”, “available” and total columns depends on the filesystem (of course used blocks (including indirect ones) are always in the “used” column, and unused blocks are always in the “available” column).

Filesystems in the ext2/ext3/ext4 **reserve** 5% of the space to the root user. This is useful on the root filesystem, to keep the system going if it fills up (in particular for logging, and to let the system administrator store a bit of data while fixing the problem). Even for data partitions such as `/home`, keeping that reserved space is useful because an almost-full filesystem is prone to fragmentation. Linux tries to avoid fragmentation (which slows down file access, especially on rotating mechanical devices such as hard disks) by pre-allocating many consecutive blocks when a file is being written, but if there are not many consecutive blocks, that can't work.

Traditional filesystems, up to and including ext4 but not btrfs, reserve a fixed number of **inodes** when the filesystem is created. This significantly simplifies the design of the filesystem, but has the downside that the number of inodes needs to be sized properly: with too many inodes, space is wasted; with too few inodes, the filesystem may run out of inodes before running out of space. The command `df -i` reports how many inodes are in use and how many are available (filesystems where the concept is not applicable may report 0).

Running `tune2fs -l` on the volume containing an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem reports some statistics including the total number and number of free inodes and blocks.

Another feature that can confuse matter is **subvolumes** (supported in [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs(command)), and in zfs under the name [datasets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5461/ftyue.html)). Multiple subvolumes share the same space, but have separate directory tree roots.

If a filesystem is mounted over the network (NFS, Samba, etc.) and the server exports a portion of that filesystem (e.g. [the server has a `/home` filesystem, and exports `/home/bob`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124650/how-to-find-the-true-disk-usage-on-my-linux-box)), then `df` on a client reflects the data for the whole filesystem, not just for the part that is exported and mounted on the client.

### What's using the space on my disk?

As we've seen above, the total size reported by `df` does not always take all the control data of the filesystem into account. Use filesystem-specific tools to get the exact size of the filesystem if needed. For example, with ext2/ext3/ext4, run `tune2fs -l` and multiply the block size by the block count.

When you create a filesystem, it normally fills up the available space on the enclosing partition or volume. Sometimes you might end up with a smaller filesystem when you've been moving filesystems around or resizing volumes.

On Linux, `lsblk` presents a nice overview of the available storage volumes. For additional information or if you don't have `lsblk`, use specialized volume management or partitioning tools to check what partitions you have. On Linux, there's `lvs`, `vgs`, `pvs` for [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management), [`fdisk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdisk#Unix-like_systems) for traditional PC-style (“MBR”) partitions (as well as GPT on recent systems), [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) for [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitions, [`disklabel`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=disklabel) for BSD disklabels, [Parted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Parted), etc. Under Linux, `cat /proc/partitions` gives a quick summary. Typical installations have at least two partitions or volumes used by the operating system: a filesystem (sometimes more), and a [swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) volume.

Some computers have a partition containing the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) or other diagnostic software. Computers with [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) have a dedicated bootloader partition.

Finally, note that most computer programs use units based on powers of 1024 = 2<sup>10</sup> (because programmers love binary and powers of 2). So 1 kB = 1024 B, 1 MB = 1048576 B, 1 GB = 1073741824, 1 TB = 1099511627776 B, … Officially, these units are known as [kibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) KiB, [mebibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) MiB, etc., but most software just reports k or kB, M or MB, etc. On the other hand, hard disk manufacturers systematically use metric (1000-based units). So that 1 TB drive is only 931 GiB or 0.904 TiB.

Comment: does the use of `tune2fs` implies to be root ? I tried on a system on which I'm not root and no luck :-(

Comment: @Kiwy `tune2fs` requires having read access to the block device that contains the filesystem, which in general requires being root since that lets you read the content of any file.

Comment: I know that 'thank you' is discouraged in SE, but Gilles you deserve a huge 'Thank you' for this terrific post.

Comment: I remember seeing a card catalog when I was like 6.  I wonder how many won't know what they are?

Comment: You discussed snapshots. I was wondering if something like a Solaris container/zone affects the analysis of the space?

Comment: @illuminÉ That's too advanced Solaris for me, I don't know at what level it fits.

Comment: And the output from ls includes un-allocated (sparce file) blocks, but excludes allocated space at the end of the last block.  du counts the allocated space in the final block twice when that block is shared by two files.  Disk space is also reserved for bad-block management and SMART data, as well as for the partition table itself.  File systems often doesn't start at the start of the partition because it can sometimes overlap boot loader code.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Solaris Zones do not affect the way space is measured. However, datasets can be delegated to non global zones. In such case, they won't be able to see other datasets sharing the same pool and then won't have all the information needed to understand the underlying disk usage. Zones also often use lofs. This file system, not mentioned in Gilles's answer, is similar to Linux bind mounts. The issues with lofs is similar to the ones that can occur with network mounted file systems, and be even more complex when combined with ZFS, which is mandatory with modern Solaris releases.

Comment: `du` **does** account for indirect blocks. That's the main difference from the file size as reported by `ls -l`.

Comment: This answer should go to Wikipedia :)

Comment: This article from RedHat gives good options for RHEL/CentOS systems https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316

Answer (score 5):

A short summary of complications to calculating file sizes and disk spaces:

- The space the file takes on disk is a multiplier of the number of blocks it takes against the size of each block + the number of inodes it takes. A 1 byte long file will take at least 1 block, 1 inode and one directory entry.

  But it could take only 1 additional directory entry if the file is a hard link to another file. It would be just another reference to the same set of blocks.
- The size of the contents of the file. This is what `ls` displays.
- Free disk space is not the size of the largest file you can fit in or the sum of all file content sizes that will fit on the disk. It's somewhere in between. It depends on the number of files (taking up inodes) the block size and how closely each file's contents fill blocks completely.

This is just scratching the surface of file systems and it is overly simplified. Also remember that different file systems operate differently.

`stat` is very helpful at spotting some of this information. Here's some examples of how to use stat and what it is good for: http://landoflinux.com/linux_stat_command_examples.html

Comment: A 1-byte file would typically take one block, not 8. Creating a hard link doesn't create an inode at all: one file is one inode no matter how many links there are to the file. Creating a hard link only requires space for the directory entry.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, admittedly my memory re: studying ext2 in depth is now a little fuzzy. I was following the output of stat re: the block count - it did feel excessive but that's what's there. I'll correct the answer.

Comment: That's because 1 ext2 block = 8 stat blocks, if the ext2 filesystem uses 4kB blocks: stat counts in 512-byte blocks for historical reasons. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/difference-between-block-size-and-cluster-size/14411#14411

Answer (score 4):

`df` is generally used to see what the file systems are, how full each is and where they're mounted. Very useful when you're running out of space in a file system, and maybe want to shift things around among the file systems, or buy a bigger disk, etc.

`du` shows details of how much cumulative storage each of one's directories is consuming (sort of like `windirstat` in Windows). Great for finding where you're hogging up space when trying to do file cleanup.

Aside from small numerical differences explained by others, I think the `du` and `df` utilities serve very different purposes.

Answer (score 3):

*I will illustrate here different cases that causes `du` being different from `df`.*

`df` counts the file system allocated blocks, `du` use the size information of each file.
A difference can have many causes:

1. Unlinked (deleted) files that are still open by application. The file information are missing, the block are still allocated.  `lsof +aL1 <filesystem>` will helps you to identify the processes. Most of the time you have to kill the processes to free the space (it depends on the process, sometimes a configuration reload is sufficient).
2. Files beneath mount points hidden to `du` but not to `df`. `debugfs` can help you to read the file system.

   ```
   $ sudo debugfs 
   debugfs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
   debugfs:  open /dev/xxx    (the desired file system  device)
   debugfs:  cd /boot
   debugfs:  ls -l 
    1966081   40755 (2)      0      0    4096 26-May-2016 16:28 .
          2   40555 (2)      0      0    4096 11-May-2016 10:43 ..
    1974291  100644 (1)      0      0       0 26-May-2016 16:28 bob   <---<<< /boot/bob is hidden by /boot fs
   ```
3. [Sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) that looks bigger than the reality. Non allocated blocks are not counted by `df` but the apparent file size is counted by `du`.

Note that Hard links do not fool `du`.