# ext3 Filesystem shows full to most apps, but only 77% full to DF

Tags: filesystems, ext3, df

Var is showing as full to many apps like Nagios, Puppet, and the LVM tools (pvs, vgs, etc)

**df -h output**

```
6.0G  4.3G  1.4G  77% /var
```

**vgs output**

```
/var/lock/lvm/V_rootvg:aux: open failed: No space left on device
  Can't get lock for rootvg
  Skipping volume group rootvg
```

`lsof +L1` shows nothing under var anymore, so I don't think there are unlinked files which have yet to be cleared from the `/var` filesystem.  I don't understand why 1.4G free on a 6G filesystem is considered full.  I know some space is reserved by the system on each filesystem but that can't be it, it's too much space.  The filesystem is `ext3` on Red Hat 5.

```
dumpe2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          c8f44510-e8f7-4e2e-950a-1410b069910e
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              393216
Block count:              1572864
Reserved block count:     78627
Free blocks:              1183083
Free inodes:              388144
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      63
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Filesystem created:       Mon Apr 29 13:12:02 2013
Last mount time:          Wed Oct 23 19:10:44 2013
Last write time:          Wed Oct 23 19:10:44 2013
Mount count:              6
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Mon Apr 29 13:12:02 2013
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      8766dfd5-c802-4bc3-81cc-21869e810656
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journal size:             32M
Journal length:           8192
Journal sequence:         0x0112568e
Journal start:            3334
```

Comment: Did you know that any files with open file handles won't be removed until the file handle is closed?

Comment: What is the output of `df -i /var`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging fwiw the `dumpe2fs` shows 388,144 inodes free.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal, to get a rough check of how much space is deleted but still opened, you might try running `lsof -s | egrep "(deleted)" | awk 'BEGIN {total=0} {total=total+$7} END{print total}'` (be forewarned, I haven't tested this)

Comment: @JoelDavis, I'm betting that count is wrong and df -i will show he is indeed out, and a fsck will fix the count in the superblock.

Comment: @JoelDavis I guess that is the number at mount time. Would be a bit extreme to write the superblock every time a file is created or deleted, wouldn't it? At any rate it seems to me that this number does not get updated during normal operation. Try for yourself.

Comment: no thanks I believe you. I just mentioned it in case it was overlooked (and I didn't notice that the last mount was back in October) which it doesn't sound like happened.

Comment: @JoelDavis I was indeed unaware that `dumpe2fs` gives this information.

Comment: Is it an option to unmount and fsck the volume (if the solution does not turn out to be the inavailability of inodes)? Shouldn't be a problem if it's not usable anyway.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/22222), does that answer you?

Comment: @psusi You were right, I am out of inodes.  What do I do now?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal if you extend the filesystem you'll get more inodes available. Since you're on LVM you can do it without unmounting the filesystem with `lvextend -r` Alternatively, you can see if there are files you can unlink.

Comment: @JoelDavis I can't even see if I have free space in the volume group because /var being broken is messing with LVM tools.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Delete a few old files in `/var/log` or move them to tmpfs or another volume.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal like I said earlier and Hauke said in the last comment, deleting a few files underneath `/var` is an option. Doing so would likely free the inodes required to create the lock file. Otherwise you can temporarily disable locking in /etc/lvm.conf by settings `locking_type = 0` (just be sure to revert the change once you've resolved the issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comments others have helped you diagnose you're out of inodes. If you need to make a few available so you can get some basic access back to your system then you could delete the following files on a CentOS 5 install, assuming you can live without them.

#### Example

```
$ sudo rm -fr /var/log/*.[1-9]?(.gz)
```

This will remove any of the previously backed up files in `/var/log`. This should buy you a few dozen inodes to start.

#### Counting inodes

*using df*

I usually use the command `df` to determine the number available.

```
$ df -i /
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                     59932672  807492 59125180    2% /
```

*using tune2fs*

You can also use `tune2fs`. With it you'll need to give it the path to the LVM LV mapper.

```
$ tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 | grep -i inode
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Inode count:              59932672
Free inodes:              59126861
Inodes per group:         32768
Inode blocks per group:   1024
First inode:              11
Inode size:       128
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       21561629
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

#### Freed up some inodes, now what?

With some breathing room you basically have a couple of options.

1. I would start by trying to quickly get a list together of files that can be targeted for deletion, so you can begin to get more headroom. I'd focus on `/tmp` and `/var` some more potential files to be removed.
2. If you have old versions of Java or anything installed under `/usr/local` or `/opt` I'd pick on those next.
3. I'd start formulating a list of installed RPMs that can be uninstalled
4. If you've been using YUM to do updates on this server you can clear out its cache.

   ```
   $ sudo yum clean all
   ```
5. Look into adding additional space.

Comment: How about `/var/log/*.[1-9]?(.gz)` for matching old log files (`extglob` required).

Comment: @Graeme - yes that's better, I'll add it, thanks. Careful or ppl will know that we've run out of inodes before 8-)

Answer (score 1):

One likely reason for running out of inodes is that a large number of files has accumulated in a particular directory for whatever reason. You could check the usual suspects, eg `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/var/log` etc. If you don't find anything, here is a command that I have cobbled together to list the top 50 directories in the filesystem containing the most files/directories in their first level.

```
find / -xdev -type d -exec sh -c '
  num=$(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 | wc -l); echo "$num $0"' {} \; |
  sort -n |
  tail -50
```

Note the top level of mount points are included as well - this is not trivial to exclude.

Comment: It was the pnp4nagios directory under /var/spool/ it creates a very large number of small files.  I ended up creating a logical volume and mounting it directly to this directory.  This resolved my issues.