# How to cat a file with "or" options

Tags: awk, cat, pcregrep

I have a file name like

```
/etc/auto.abc on server 1
/etc/auto.def on server 2
/etc/auto.ghi on server 1
```

I am writing a single script for all servers and in that I want to cat the file.

Example: cat `/etc/auto.abc` or `/etc/auto.def` or `/etc/auto.ghi`. It should able to take the file which is present.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a script to check for the existence of the file prior to trying to run an operation on it?

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -f "/etc/auto.def"; then cat /etc/auto.def;
elif test -f "/etc/auto.ghi"; then cat /etc/auto.ghi;
elif test -f "/etc/auto.abc"; then cat /etc/auto.abc;fi
```

Sources:

http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Check-If-a-File-Exists

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/

Comment: readarray -t array <<< "$(pdc status -a 2>&1 | cat /etc/auto.*  | grep -v "autotab" | cut -f1)". I am using a cat command in above statement and if I use the loop it will be complicated

Comment: @venella Why use cat at all if you are using grep? See `man grep`

Comment: My requirement is I need the contents of the file by eliminating the lines having "autotab". Either one among the 3 files the server will be having.

Comment: in that case `grep -v "autotab" /etc/auto` should provide the same output as `cat /etc/auto.* | grep -v "autotab"  Some kind soul once referred me to the [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) award for one of my answers. I've been stuck on studying man pages ever since and cat  has been relegated to it's intended use to concatenate files.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
if [[ $(find . -name "auto*" -type f -maxdepth 1 -printf '\n' | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]
then
   cat auto*
else
   echo there are more files that match 'auto*'
fi
```

`-printf '\n'` is there to handle filenames which contain newlines correctly (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123531/how-can-i-count-all-the-files-on-my-system-from-root)). In `else` you should handle the situation if there are more than 1 file which matches `auto*` pattern - it's your decision what to do here.

Comment: Existence test. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [file globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)?

The most permissive way would be:

```
cat /etc/auto*
```

But better in your case would be:

```
cat /etc/auto.???
```

Of course *if* there could be other unwanted files matching that glob, or *if* there could be more than one of the three files present (and you only want one), this doesn't take into account all those possibilities.  But it's certainly the *simplest* way.