# How to find the true disk usage on my Linux box?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, disk

I have a linux box on my school's server. When I was trying to install `Protocol Buffers`, disk usage is reported as exceeded. So I checked my disk usage by two command on my home directory:

```
du -h 
535M    .

df -ha
home.XXX:/export/home/XXX                 
9.7T  1.5T  8.3T  15% /home/XXX
```

Are they supposed to be same number? Which one is the real usage of my disk on Linux box?

Comment: Are there any Quotas set up ?

Comment: yes, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` tells you how much data there is in the directory where you ran it. `df` tells you how much data is in total on the volume where your home directory is located. Your home directory is mounted remotely (over NFS); it is likely that it is on the same volume as other home directories, so `df` reports the data used by all the home directories on the same volume.

Your disk space may be exceeded even if there is room left on the device. A school environment is highly likely to have [quotas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) in place. If you got a message “quota exceeded” as opposed to “no space left on device”, then you've exceeded your quota. Run the command `quota` to see what your quota is and how much of it you're using.