# Deciphering Disk Usage. Where Did the Space Go?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, amazon-ec2

## The System

- An instance running on *Amazon EC2*
- It is an *m1.large* EC2 instance
- The instance is running *Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS*

## Here's What Happens...

To begin, let's execute the following:

```
root@host:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      9.9G  6.6G  2.8G  71% /
udev            3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           746M  184K  745M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       414G  199M  393G   1% /mnt
```

The output above tells us that 199 MB or 1% of `/dev/xvdb` (our ephemeral storage) is in use. However, the output of `ls` tells us the device is pretty much empty.

```
root@host:~# ls -lah /mnt
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Nov 11 11:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4.0K May  1 15:57 ..
drwx------  2 root root  16K Nov 11 11:27 lost+found
```

What is consuming all the space?

## Edit: Additional Information...

As advised in the comments below, here is the output of `du -sch /mnt`:

```
root@host:~# du -sch /mnt
20K     /mnt
20K     total
```

... and here is the output of `mount`:

```
root@host:~# mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/xvdb on /mnt type ext3 (rw)
```

Comment: What's in `lost+found`? What's the size of that folder?

Comment: The output of `ls -lah /mnt` above says `/mnt` is 16K.

Comment: That does not include the size of the subdirectories. Please run `du -sch /mnt/lost+found`.

Comment: Ah. Nonetheless, `du -sch /mnt/lost+found` is reporting 16K also.

Comment: OK, in that case, first check out [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/). If it still does not answer your question, [edit] your post and add the output of `mount` and replace the `ls -lah /mnt` (which is really not relevant at all) with `du -sch /mnt`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage might have some useful information.

Comment: What does `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/xvdb` show?

Answer (score 0):

try `du -hk /mnt` to see the disk usage