# Why does du and quota results not match?

Tags: disk-usage, quota

I have exceeded my disk quota on a system which I do not have root access. I tried removing old files but am still over. I tried runing `du` to find where I am using up all my space but it reports I am using very little.

Results from `quota`

```
   /home/1234$ quota -s
   Disk quotas for user 1234 (uid 1234): 
        Filesystem   space   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
       cslab:/home   4519M*  4096M   5120M   09:47    6155       0       0
```

From `du`

```
   /home/1234$ du -mad 1
   ...
   936     total
```

I don't understand why `quota` says I am using 4.5GB while `du` only counts .9GB.
I also checked for files I own in `/tmp` and there was 50MB worth of files there. *Where could the other 3.5GB of files be? Is it possible the quota system is wrong and needs reset?*

Comment: Check if [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage) helps. Is this over NFS? There may be some caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there may be some files still held open by some processes. You can try to list them using,

```
lsof | grep username | grep deleted
```

A more better version would be to use,

```
lsof +L1 | grep username
```

However, sometimes there might be discrepancy in the output between `du` and `quota` which is explained in this [link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afos). Excerpt from the link,

> In Unix, the du and quota commands may report different values. The
>   reason for this discrepancy is that the process which goes through the
>   file system, checks quotas, and updates the usage tables only runs at
>   specific times. Therefore, there will be periods between quota checks
>   that the quota -v command will report incorrect disk usage. Use the du
>   command for the most accurate information about the size of your
>   files.

Comment: I have tried this but there are no open deleted files.

Comment: @BrandonClements, Is [this](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afos) link useful?

Comment: The link was useful, I did not consider that quota was only updated periodically. I will have to wait and see if this indeed my problem, but i think it is. Could you please move the link and a brief description into your answer.

Comment: @BrandonClements, updated. Let me know if you need more information!

Comment: It looks like it fixed itself overnight. For others who read this answer I would note that deleting small files appeared to have an immediate effect on my quota so I was not sure this was the case. It does appear to be so.

Answer (score 2):

`quota` works by querying the filesystem for the blocks actually occupied by your files.

`du` works by scanning directories recursively for your files.

The two methods could yield different results.  For example, when you "delete" a file, then it is no longer visible when listing the directory.  However, the blocks on the disk are not actually freed until the last filehandle on it is closed.  In that case, the file is invisible to `du`, but still counts against your quota.