# Difference between block size and file size in quota

Tags: linux, quota

So I would like know the Difference between `block limits` and `file limits` in quota ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as a newbie I'd suggest you read [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage), just to get a handle on what things like **block** mean.

The underlying reason is because [sometimes people can cheat quota's](https://superuser.com/questions/973213/how-can-a-file-size-be-zero), by storing text in file names, etc.  As such it can be useful for an admin to place restrictions on blocks as well as files.