# How to determine quota(1) block size?

Tags: filesystems, quota

Google has parsed [this Duke University IT knowledgebase article](https://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/faqs/quotas_about) into an infocard alleging to *anyone* searching "linux quota block size" that

> A block quota is the limit on the actual amount of disk space that can be used by an account. This space is measured in 1 KB blocks (1 KB = 1024 bytes or characters).

A quick search on this site yielded [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232219/26420) referring to *other* definitions of "block size", including EXT4's:

> A typical block size is 4KiB.

I poked around in [these source files](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/quota/quota-tools/+/refs/tags/v4.04) a bit, but their code is so sparsely commented that I was unable to grok it.

I still vaguely **assume** that `quota(1)` reports "block size" in the associated filesystem's specific block (size rather than a universal constant like 1KiB), but how could I **verify** this? Where is the point of contact between the quota tooling codebase and the filesystem driver codebase?

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal constant of block size; "The UNIX Programming
Environment" (1984) on page 50 states for `du(1)`

> The filenames are obvious; the numbers are the number of disc blocks
> -- typically 512 or 1024 bytes each -- of storage for each file.

4096 is also popular these days.

That being said, for the http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxquota/
tools (which may differ from other implementations) the `edquota(8)`
documentation indicates

> Block  usage  and  limits are reported and interpereted as multiples of
> kibibyte (1024 bytes) blocks by default. Symbols K, M, G, and T can  be
> appended  to  numeric value to express kibibytes, mebibytes, gibibytes,
> and tebibytes.

And in `xfs_quota(8)` one might find

> There  are  four  numbers  for  each  limit:  current usage, soft limit
> (quota), hard limit, and time limit.  The soft limit is the  number  of
> 1K-blocks  (or  files)  that the user is expected to remain below.
> ...
> report [ -gpu ] [ -bir ] [ -ahntlLNU ] [ -f file ]
> Report  filesystem  quota  information.   This reports all quota
> usage for a filesystem, for  the  specified  quota  type  (u/g/p
> and/or  blocks/inodes/realtime).  It reports blocks in 1KB units
> by default. The -h option reports in a  "human-readable"  format
> similar  to  the df(1) command.

"interpereted as multiples of" could easily support 4096; a user
consuming one 4096 block on a `-b 4096` filesystem should be reported as
consuming four 1024 blocks by the quota system. This might be slightly
inaccurate for a 1024 byte lens of a 512 block filesystem. However
according to `mkfs.ext2` EXT2 only supports 1024 blocks or larger:

> OPTIONS
> -b block-size
> Specify  the  size  of blocks in bytes.  Valid block-size values
> are 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes per block.

So converting those to 1024 bytes for display would never be wrong,
provided the program can do the math aright.

XFS allows you to create `-b 512` filesystems, so an easy test for
verification there would be to create a `-b 512` filesystem and a `-b 1024` filesystem, enable quotas on them, and write 512 bytes for a user
on both. If the 1024-for-quota-display holds, both of them should show 1
block consumed. Then write 512 more bytes, and they still both should
show 1 block used.

```
head -c 512 /dev/zero > a_test_file
```

Otherwise you could test with a `-b 4096` filesystem and see if the
quotas are reported in units of 1024 as the documentation for the quota
or filesystems listed above indicates it should be. For other quota
software, check the documentation, and verify by performing file write
tests. File write tests are a pretty good way to know if the hard limits
are working, that the warnings and reporting are all good, that suitable
documentation exists, etc.