# du/df and ls reporting different disk usage

Tags: files, filesystems, ls, disk-usage

At the end of last week one of my colleagues noticed something strange on one of our shared compute servers.

We have a directory which `ls -l` shows as containing a file which is 132G in size.

However, running `df -h` shows that the total amount of space used on the disk as 128G. Additionally running `du -h --max-depth=1` on the root of the drive also reports 128G for `.`

Initially I wondered whether this issue might be as a result of open file handles or similar causing these binaries to report different information. However, I have tired unmounting and remounting the disk and all binaries report the same results as before.

To give a bit more information on the configuration of the drive:

- The volume is formatted using EXT4 on top of LUKS encryption.
- The disk is not shared via NFS or similar.
- I have check the file in question and it does not appear to be linked.
- When unmounting and remounting the volume I forced a disk check, by running `fsck -f` on the volume, and no issues were returned.
- The server the disk is located on isn't a virtualisation host and is running Ubuntu 14.04 as the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your server virtualization host?

Different real file and disk space size is normal behaviour for dynamically expanding virtual disks. This disks has different real file size and header filesize data

**Example**:

possibly you use qemu virtual disks (qcow2 extension or other) which you can find with:

```
find / -regex '.*\.qcow.*$'

/var/lib/vz/images/105/vm-105-disk-1.qcow2
...
```

Lets check `vm-105-disk-1.qcow2` size with `stat`:

```
stat vm-105-disk-1.qcow2

  File: vm-100-disk-1.qcow2
  Size: 68745560064
```

79728541696 - is approxymately 64GB

Check with `wc`:

```
wc -c <vm-105-disk-1.qcow2

68745560064
```

The same result... Check with `du`:

```
du -sh vm-105-disk-1.qcow2

15G        vm-105-disk-1.qcow2
```

Only 15GB! Lets check with `qemu-img` util:

```
qemu-img info vm-105-disk-1.qcow2

image: vm-105-disk-1.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 64G (68719476736 bytes)
disk size: 14G
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

Pay attention at this two lines and everything should be clear:

```
virtual size: 64G (68719476736 bytes)
disk size: 14G
```

---

If your server is not virtualization host, see this topics:

- [What is the difference between du -h and ls -lh?](https://serverfault.com/questions/290088/what-is-the-difference-between-du-h-and-ls-lh)
- [`du -b` shows different size than `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247429/du-b-shows-different-size-than-ls)
- And the last one [Why ls and du show different size?](https://superuser.com/questions/94217/why-ls-and-du-show-different-size)

Comment: Thanks @Egor! That's good to know. Unfortunately the sever in question isn't a virtualisation host, instead the OS is running on the bare hardware. I'll add update my post to make that clearer.

Comment: @PicoutputCls, i added the answer, see above

Comment: Thanks @EgorVasilyev for the update! It turns out the issue I was having is related to sparse files, as explained fully in the last of those three links: [Why ls and du show different size?](https://superuser.com/questions/94217/why-ls-and-du-show-different-size) Adding `--apparent-size` to `du` makes everything consistent.