# why Inode file size is different than actual size

Tags: filesystems, ext4, inode

I noticed one log file having less size than what's mentioned in inode.

```
$ ls -lhtr /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 fk-3p-kafka fk-3p 11G Apr 10 18:27 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
$ du -sh /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
2.4G    /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
$# stat /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
  File: `/var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log'
  Size: 11038186491 Blocks: 4823840    IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe01h/65025d    Inode: 132380      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 7100/fk-3p-kafka)   Gid: ( 7100/   fk-3p)
Access: 2016-03-09 22:47:06.822168512 +0530
Modify: 2016-04-10 18:28:11.022285512 +0530
Change: 2016-04-10 18:28:11.022285512 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Next thing I did was to check for any deleted file handlers.

```
$ lsof | grep kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252       fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038227512     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252   347 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252   712 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252   764 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038224580     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  2538 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038224580     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  3241 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038224580     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  3498 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038224580     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  4146 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038224580     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  4147 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038224580     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  4148 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038224580     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  6935 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  7650 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  9530 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252  9581 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 10816 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 11887 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038227512     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 13732 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22255 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038204079     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22256 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038204079     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22257 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038204079     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22258 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038204079     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22259 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038204079     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22260 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038204079     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22261 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038205544     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22262 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038205544     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22263 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038205544     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22264 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038205544     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22265 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038205544     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22266 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038205544     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22267 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22268 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22269 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22270 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22271 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22272 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22273 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22274 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038207009     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22275 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22276 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22277 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22278 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22279 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22280 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22281 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22282 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038208473     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22283 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038209937     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22284 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038209937     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22285 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038209937     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22286 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038209937     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22287 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038209937     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22288 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038209937     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22289 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038209937     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22290 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22291 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22292 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22293 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22294 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22295 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22296 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22297 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038211401     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22298 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22299 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22300 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22301 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22302 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22303 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22304 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22305 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038212865     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22306 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22307 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22308 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22309 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22310 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22311 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22312 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22313 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22317 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038214329     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22318 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22319 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22320 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22321 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22322 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22323 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22324 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22325 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22326 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038215793     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22327 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22328 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22329 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22330 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22331 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22332 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22333 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22334 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038217258     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22335 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22336 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22337 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22338 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22339 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22340 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22341 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22342 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22343 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038218724     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22344 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22345 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22349 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22352 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22367 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 22450 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26510 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26511 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26740 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038220188     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26741 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26749 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26750 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26758 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 26759 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 28172 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038227512     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 28173 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038227512     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 28174 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038227512     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 31036 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 31187 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 31339 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038221652     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 31389 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 31692 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32151 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32350 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32452 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32603 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32606 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32607 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038226047     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32608 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038227512     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32654 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
java      22252 32755 fk-3p-kafka    3w      REG              254,1 11038223116     132380 /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log
```

Clearly there were no deleted FD for kafkaServer-gc.log. I tried truncating the file too but file size in inode is not changing. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Use `filefrag -v /var/log/test/fk-3p-kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log` to see how the file is laid out on disk. It's probably highly fragmented, giving an extremely long and impenetrable `filefrag` report, but it will be obvious in the first few lines if the first block's offset is ~9 gigs in.

Answer (score 8):

Given that this is a log file, here's the most likely explanation:

- There is a process that has the file open and keeps appending to it. Currently that's process 22252, there may have been other processes in the past (previous instances of the same application).
- At some point in the past, someone truncated the file. Truncating the file to a certain position removes all the data past that position, but it doesn't affect the position of a process that's appending to a file.

Let's say the file was truncated to position 0. Then, immediately after the truncation operation, the file size was 0. But the Java process had the file open, and had its current position set to *n*. The next time the Java process wrote to the log file, it wrote from position *n* to *n* + *k* (where *k* is the number of bytes that it wrote), so after this point the file size was *n* + *k*, and it continued growing as the Java process wrote more.

The disk usage¹ is less than the file size because the truncation deleted all the storage used for the file content. When the process appended to the file after the truncation, that turned the file into a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file): all bytes before position *n* are null bytes, but blocks consisting entirely of null bytes are not re-created. Let's say that *n* = 1024567 and the block size is 1024 bytes, then on the first append operation after truncation, a block for positions 1024000–1025023 was created, with 567 null bytes followed by the *k* bytes of that log message.

Deleting a file that's still open wouldn't affect either its disk usage or its file size, but it would make the file invisible to `du` and `ls` while still occupying space that's recorded as in use by `df`. See [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage)

¹  <sub>The number of blocks used by the file — both it and the file size are stored in the inode, so don't call the disk usage “inode file size”!</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), i.e. a file that is largely empty, and where not all the disc blocks needed for the full size have been allocated.

Using `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 seek=1E of=sparse` I just made a file with an apparent size of 1 EB and I don't have that much disc space:

```
grove@cassiopeia> ls -lh sparse  
-rw-r--r-- 1 grove grove 1.1E Apr 10 23:53 sparse
grove@cassiopeia> du sparse      
4       sparse
grove@cassiopeia> stat sparse    
  File: `sparse'
  Size: 1152921504606846977     Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 902h/2306d      Inode: 1922068     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   grove)   Gid: ( 1000/   grove)
Access: 2016-04-10 23:53:00.925240922 +0200
Modify: 2016-04-10 23:53:00.925240922 +0200
Change: 2016-04-10 23:53:00.925240922 +0200
 Birth: -
```