# Why does baobab estimate my usage as less than half compared to du or pan_quota?

Tags: disk-usage

On a `panfs` filesystem:

- `pan_quota` says I'm using 8.67 GB.
- `du -hcsx` says I'm using 8.1 GB.
- `baobab` says I'm using 3.3 GB.

This is for my home directory, with a 8 GB soft and 10 GB hard quota.  What might cause the modest discrepancy between `du`and `pan_quota`?  And what may cause the huge discrepancy between `baobab` and either `du` or `pan_quota`?

The difference is not due to one or two specific files, but propagates down and is present for smaller and larger directories alike.

Comment: Do you have a lot of tiny files? Could be a logical v. physical size difference; what does `du --apparent-size -hcsx` give?

Comment: Have you read [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage)?

Comment: @derobert 34301 files, blocksize 64 kB.  The `du --apparent-size -hcsx` command you suggest gives the same answer as `baobab`.

Comment: @derobert I have partly.  I thought the differences I found are too large to be explained by it, but perhaps I was wrong.  Block size is apparently 64k.

Comment: @gerrit That's what's going on then, it's small files eating an entire block. A 64k block size is pretty big. The question Gilles linked explains in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk space used by a file includes more than the size of the contents. Most filesystems use fixed-size blocks; if a file's size isn't a multiple of the block size, then the last block is only partially filled. `du` counts the total number of blocks, which is usually a little more than the sum of the file sizes since it also includes the part of the last block that isn't filled.

I think the difference between `pan_quota` and `du -h` is due to the fact that the PANFS filesystem doesn't report its block size accurately. The [JASMIN FAQ](http://www.jasmin.ac.uk/faq/#du) suggests using `pand_du` instead of `du`.

It seems that on your machine, Baobab is displaying the sum of the file sizes. That's the number you get with `du --appparent-size`. Baobab displays the actual disk usage on my machine (but with 1GB = 10<sup>9</sup> bytes, whereas `du -h` uses 1GB = 2<sup>30</sup> bytes); I think this is because you're using a version older than this change

```
commit dbcbe27e0452eeacbc4a253f1b0b1a06708834de
Author: Paolo Borelli <pborelli@gnome.org>
Date:   2012-01-07

    Use the STANDARD_ALLOCATED_SIZE file attribute.
```

but I haven't traced it down to make sure.

For more information about disk usage discrepancies, see [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage)

Comment: I neglected to mention that I don't run baobab on the host machine (where it is unavailable), but through sshfs, so perhaps that prevents baobab from performing an accurate calculation.