# New FS size differs from LV size

Tags: ext4

I create a 4 GByte sized LV on a RHEL6 machine.

I created a 4 GByte sized EXT4 FS.

```
[root@server ~]# lvcreate -n newlvnamehere -L 4096M rootvg
  Logical volume "newlvnamehere" created.
[root@server ~]# mkdir /newfshere
[root@server ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/rootvg-newlvnamehere
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=1 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
262144 inodes, 1048576 blocks
52428 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=1073741824
32 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736

Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 35 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.
[root@server ~]# mount /dev/mapper/rootvg-newlvnamehere /newfshere
[root@server ~]# df -m /newfshere
Filesystem           1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-newlvnamehere
                      3904     8      3691   1% /newfshere
```

If I later use resise2fs it says nothing to do..

**Question**: Why doesn't the EXT4 FS has the exact same size as the LV? It is only 3904 MByte sized and the LV is 4096. Where did 192 MByte went? 4096-3904.

PE size in the rootvg is 32 MByte. FS Journal size: 128M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filesystem does have exactly the same size as the LV: `mkfs.ext4` says

> 262144 inodes, 1048576 blocks

which is 4GB. The missing 192MB are accounted for by the journal (128MB) and the filesystem data structures (superblocks and backups).

[Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage/120312#120312) has lots more detail.