# HDD size from df or lsblk?

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, size, lsblk

I've been said to write a program in c++ to get every hdd and partition's total, free and used size. I can use commands to do this. 
 I searched and I understood that there are two ways of getting size, lsblk and df. I know there are differences between outputs because of : [why df get result inconsistent with lsblk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336462/why-df-get-result-inconsistent-with-lsblk) 
 so which one should I chose?(also I can't have used and free sizes in lsblk)
 I use ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

As you are writing a C++ program, I'd recommend a third and fourth way:

- Get partition total size from `/sys/block/sd*/sd*/size`.
- Get filesystem used size and filesystem free size by calling `statfs`, see `man statfs` for details. Yes, this only works when the partition is mounted.

Faster, and you don't have to parse output, and you are not screwed in the (unlikely) event that `df` or `lsblk` decide to change their output format.