# du command shows larger size than nand erase block size in ubifs. How to check the exact size in ubifs?

Tags: root, disk-usage, block-device, root-filesystem, ubifs

I use UBIFS for rootfs.
I would like to check the size of each direcotries in /.

When I checked with du command, it shows larger than mtd size.
Would you tell me the way how can I check the correct size of each directories?

## detail

```
$ du -sh /
508M /

Physical Erase Block (PEB) is 128KB. Logical Erase Block (LEB) of UBI is 124KB.

mtdinfo command shows as follows:
mtd4
Name:                           rootfs
Type:                           nand
Eraseblock size:                131072 bytes, 128.0 KiB
Amount of eraseblocks:          3664 (480247808 bytes, 458.0 MiB)
Minimum input/output unit size: 2048 bytes
Sub-page size:                  2048 bytes
OOB size:                       64 bytes
Character device major/minor:   90:8
Bad blocks are allowed:         true
Device is writable:             true
```

Amount of eraseblocks is 458MB, but du command shows 508MB.
It is strange. Why du shows larger size?

#### added

```
$df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
ubi0:rootfs     400M  274M  126M  69% /
devtmpfs         89M   28K   89M   1% /dev
tmpfs           249M  144K  249M   1% /run
tmpfs           249M  156K  249M   1% /var/volatile
```

Comment: Not all files on your ubifs at /.

Comment: Thank you. I know all files are not in / and some are in RAMdisk. I added the result of "df -h". Please check it.

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage/120312#120312

Comment: Thanks. I read it and the other article in stackexchange. However I could not understand how I can know the correct max size and usage.