# Should I use df or du to calculate space to use for partitioning?

Tags: usb, disk-usage, storage

I want to back up `/home` dir, but the `sudo du -h /home | tail -n1` shows

```
22146824    /home
```

however `df -h` shows:

```
/dev/sda5        54G   22G   30G  42% /home

22*2^30 == 23622320128
```

The later number is much bigger then the first, and they should show the same disk usage? What number of space should I use, if I want to make partition on floppy disk?

Comment: The inevitable reference: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/315749). A common reason for `df` showing more used space than `du` is deleted files. Refer to the exhaustive answer to the linked question for a list of other possible causes.

Comment: @fra-san yes, that is a lot of info, but there is no mention what to use for making partition, which is for practical reason. Now that is the question, should I make partition with `22GiB` according to `df` or cca `0.0207GiB` according to `du`? (where I will then `rsync` it to floppy)

Comment: Is really `22146824` coming from `du -h`? Which version of `du`? I thought `22146824` was in KiB (actually from `du` with no `-h`). The difference between the used space as reported by those two tools is usually modest (e.g. 66 MiB out of 114 GiB for my `/` right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a file system then you do not only need space for the data but also for the metadata. Thus `du` (ignoring the metadata) shows too little capacity.

The `df` number is relevant for this case.