# ls -s vs -l file size difference and significance

Tags: filesystems, ls, size

As a very basic linux user, I've always considered the file size as shown in `ls -lh` to be the one and only file size on disk.

For example here, `file.xlsx` is 11kb

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 michael  staff    11K May 29  2020 file.xlsx
```

However, I noticed with the `-s` flag, the filesize displayed is now 24.

```
   24 -rw-r--r--@  1 michael  staff    11K May 29  2020 file.xlsx
```

I eventually found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/269531/1224856) which explained that `-s` shows the file size *on the file system*, along with the following example:

```
# truncate -s 128 f_zeroes.img
# hexdump -vC f_zeroes.img 
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080

# truncate -s 128 f_zeroes.img
# hexdump -vC f_zeroes.img 
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080
```

and when I run `ls -lsh` I get the following:

```
# ls -lsh
total 4.0K
4.0K -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 128 Apr 26 18:44 f_random.img
   0 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 128 Apr 26 18:43 f_zeroes.img
```

The explanation is that `f_zeroes.img` takes up 0 on the filesystem because it's still all 0s, whereas `f_random.img` takes up more space due to actual characters.

My question is thus: I'm sure both values have it's usage, and so which value matters when? If I have all these files taking up 0 on the file system, does that mean I am theoretically using less space than what the `-l` flag is telling me?

Comment: The `24` that is shown is the number of file system blocks used by the file. You may want to read [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311)

Comment: I've added an explicit mention of `ls -s` to our [reference answer on the topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage), which already explained what's going on, just didn't mention that you could get the block count with `ls -s`.