# Created a new volume on a 10TB (9.1TiB) hard drive, getting conflicting information regarding free space!

Tags: filesystems, partition, hard-disk, disk-usage, ext4

`gparted` reports 74GB used and 9.02TiB available (seems reasonable).

`df` reports 40MB used, but only shows 8.6TiB available (suddenly 425 GiB missing)

Disk Info in the file manager reports similar to `df`, showing 0 bytes used but only 8.6TiB available

Am I actually losing over 5% of my disk to overhead?

[image: gparted]
[image: df]
[image: disk info]

Comment: somehow related : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120311/why-are-there-so-many-different-ways-to-measure-disk-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this [over on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/282317/disk-space-overhead-in-ext4) - the reserved blocks for root-owned processes by default take 5% of your drive. I lowered this to 0% using `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdb1` and now I am showing all my free space, as espected.

Comment: 5% is probably excessive on modern, multi-terabyte drives, but it's still a good idea to keep some in reserve for root, just in case you need to do any emergency repairs/rescues/mv/etc on the filesystem.  I recommend setting it to 1%, not 0%.   Or use `tune2fs -r` to set it to an exact number of reserved blocks, e.g `tune2fs -r 100000` for 100,000 blocks

Comment: Also, the 5% is not just for root, but also to avoid excessive/persistent fragmentation. Whether you need 5% is a separate question, but 0% is bad and can permanently hurt performance if ever completely filled.