# My linux is using 100% of my ssd for no reason

Tags: linux, btrfs, ssd

The largest folders I have on the system

```
WARNING:

Full balance without filters requested. This operation is very
intense and takes potentially very long. It is recommended to
use the balance filters to narrow down the scope of balance.
Use 'btrfs balance start --full-balance' option to skip this
warning. The operation will start in 10 seconds.
Use Ctrl-C to stop it.

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Starting balance without any filters.
ERROR: error during balancing ‘/’: Read-only file system
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail

Device size: 461.26GiB
Device allocated: 461.26GiB
Device unallocated: 1.00MiB
Device missing: 0.00B
Device slack: 3.50KiB
Used: 457.69GiB
Free (estimated): 179.18MiB (min: 179.18MiB)
Free (statfs, df): 179.18MiB
Data ratio: 1.00
Metadata ratio: 2.00
Global reserve: 512.00MiB (used: 0.00B)
Multiple profiles: no

Data,single: Size:435.24GiB, Used:435.07GiB (99.96%)
/dev/nvme1n1p3 435.24GiB

Metadata,DUP: Size:13.00GiB, Used:11.31GiB (87.00%)
/dev/nvme1n1p3 26.00GiB

System,DUP: Size:8.00MiB, Used:64.00KiB (0.78%)
/dev/nvme1n1p3 16.00MiB

Unallocated:
/dev/nvme1n1p3 1.00MiB
```

[image: disk usage]

Comment: `ERROR: error during balancing ‘/’: Read-only file system
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail` Did you try that? What info did it have?

Comment: Please add output of commands `df -h` and  `sudo du -sch /*`.

Comment: Nothing here to indicate what is 100% used.

Comment: "Used: 457.69GiB
Free (estimated): 179.18MiB (min: 179.18MiB)"

Comment: ![image](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/KzrIXvUBDRea.png?o=1)

Comment: I tried using the command "btrfs balance start /" and got this error

Comment: What happens with `btrfs balance start -dusage=0 -musage=0 /`?

Comment: Without sudo: ERROR: unable to start balance, another exclusive operation 'balance' in progress
With sudo: Done, had to relocate 0 out of 454 chunks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710742/272818

Comment: It worked! I think I'll stop making backups, just one backup takes up 100gb, how horrible!