# ls -alh and du -sh shows difference in size.. why is that?

Tags: linux, ls, disk-usage, size

Why is this size difference ? Can someone explain ?

```
[root@~] ls  -alh /vmfs/volumes/50a4a9e6-13184850/SYD0TXT01/vmware.log
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        2.1G Nov 25 00:48 /vmfs/volumes/50a4a9e6-13184850/SYD0TXT01/vmware.log

[root@:~] du -sh /vmfs/volumes/50a4a9e6-13184850/SYD0TXT01/vmware.log
0       /vmfs/volumes/50a4a9e6-13184850/SYD0TXT01/vmware.log
```

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/94220/1224462) may be useful for you

Comment: Can you say more about the file and the filesystem it's residing on please? Is it a virtual disk file, is it residing on a disk with a native filesystem? Is the file a text file or some sparse binary format?

Comment: In general: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/108618)